# Combinatorial Proof: $ {a \choose b} {b \choose c} = {a \choose a-c}{a-c \choose b-c}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Let $0\le c \le b \le a $. Show the identity is true with combinatorial proof. 
$ {a \choose b} {b \choose c} = {a \choose a-c}{a-c \choose b-c}$. By using algebra, I can find out that both sides are dividing $a$ into 3 sets $(a-b), (b-c), c$, but I have no clue how to use combinatorial proof. The multiplication part is confusing.

Edit: I didn't know this question has been asked before. After looking at the hint, is it correct to say we choose committee first because we have ${a \choose a-c}$ which is same as  ${a \choose c}$?

Edit: LHS is saying we choose $b$ out of $a$ into group I and then we choose $c$ out of $b$ into group II. RHS is saying we take $a-c$ out of $a$ in the group II. Then group II would be left with $c$. Next we choose $b-c$ out of $a-c$ into group I. Thus, group I and group II have same numbers on both sides. Is this right? And is this a complete proof?

Comment: Hint: Consider the number of ways to choose a committee of size $b$ and a sub-committee of size $c$ from a group of $a$ people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show $\dbinom{a}{b}\dbinom{b}{c}=\dbinom{a}{a-c}\dbinom{a-c}{a-b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701344/show-dbinomab-dbinombc-dbinomaa-c-dbinoma-ca-b) Indeed @WhatsUp

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it has been asked before. How do I find out if my question has been asked before? I couldn't show that ${a \choose b}$ in the search, or could I?

Comment: I just look at the hint. For the right hand side, we pick the committee first because ${ a \choose a-c}$ is same as ${a \choose c}$. Is that right?